# If R(z) and S(z) be two rational functions, if $\forall |z|=1,R(z)=Q(z) $, how to prove $R(z)\equiv Q(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If R(z) and S(z) be two rational function( i.e. $R(z)=\frac {P(z)}{Q(z)}$ where P(z) and Q(z) are polynomials ), if $\forall |z|=1,R(z)=Q(z) $, how to prove  $R(z)\equiv Q(z)$.

Comment: Note that if two polynomials agree on an infinite set, then they're identically equal.

Comment: I'm confused. What is $S$?

Comment: @FrankScience: If two polynomials agree on a **finite** set of suitable size they are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given four polynomials, $p(z),q(z),r(z),s(z)$, where $q(z)\not=0$ and $s(z)\not=0$ for $|z|=1$, such that $$\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}=\frac{r(z)}{s(z)},$$ for every $z$ where $q(z)\not=0$ and $s(z)\not=0$. Then, $$p(z)s(z)-r(z)q(z)=0,$$ for every $|z|=1$. Hence, by the maximum modulus principle, $$p(z)s(z)-r(z)q(z)=0$$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Hence, $$\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}=\frac{r(z)}{s(z)},$$ for every $z$ where $q(z)\not=0$ and $s(z)\not=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're trying to show $R(z) \equiv S(z)$ instead of $Q(z)$.

Consider the polynomial $T(z)=R(z)-S(z)$ and consider the zeroes of $T(z)$. For what $z$ is $T(z)=0$? If the numerator of $T(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, how many zeroes can it possibly have?

Comment: For that matter, any two meromorphic (not just rational) functions $R,S$ satisfying $R=S$ on $\{|z|=1\}$ must be equal everywhere.